# C++ How can I ignore symbols when reading a file?

Tags: c++

this is my current read file code:

```
void Dictionary::processFile() {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("article.txt");
    if (fin.fail( )) {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    string word;

    while (!fin.eof()) {
        fin >> word;
        cout << word << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    fin.close();
}
```

How can I make my code ignore symbols(".';:! etc.) and only output/read words? at the moment it is reading every single symbol on the article. example "test.", "them,"

Comment: What kind of symbol d you mean? Can you provide a minimal example for `article.txt`?

Comment: Don't use `!fin.eof()` in the while condition, instead put `fin >>word` directly as the conditon. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1942027) for more info.

Comment: @smkanadl basically all symbols like . , ; ' " / ! @ etc.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl when I tried using fin>>word it skipped the first and last word in my txt file. why?

Comment: You included ' in the undesired symbols. What's the expected behavior with words like "what's", "don't" or "I'll"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read "words" much like you do now, but then filter out the unwanted characters from the string before printing the "word".

C++ have many [algorithmic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can help you with this. For your purpose you could look at e.g. [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and do something like

```
static std::string const symbols = "\".';:!";

while (fin >> word)
{
    word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end() [symbols&](char const& ch) {
        return std::any_of(symbols.begin(), symbols.end(), [ch](char const& sym) {
            return ch == sym;
        });
    });

    if (!word.empty())
    {
        // Do something with the "word"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not particularly performant, however. Not as compared with filtering on input in the first place, at least.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit do you mean reading a line and process a character at a time to separete tokens(words)?

Comment: @Bob__: I don't know what you're asking me.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Boost.Iostrems, you may to write own InputFilter for your stream. See the details here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/writing_filters.html